# WinHTTP and MSXML hangs on .Send() forever

Tags: windows, http, winapi, connect, autoit

I'm trying to create an app that connects several times to an internal API on my office. These are simple GET requests to a server on the same network (accessed through IP). But in some of our machines, the `.Send()` hangs forever. Here is the code:

```
Func get_url($RequestURL)
    ;Global $oHTTP = ObjCreate("winhttp.winhttprequest.5.1") ; didn't work too
    Local $oHTTP = ObjCreate("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")
    $oHTTP.Open("GET", $RequestURL, False)
    $oHTTP.Send()
     if  $oHTTP.status == 200 Then
           Return $oHTTP.ResponseText
     Else
            Return  SetError($oHTTP.status, 0, False)
     EndIf
 EndFunc
```

While the same code worked well in some machines, in other, it hangs forever on the `$oHTTP.Send()`. On these machines, however, I can connect to the IP using telnet, netcat and any web browser without any problem. The firewall is turned off on both sides.

While researching about it, I saw that it's not just me who face this problem, but none of the topics I found had a solution. Was this feature deprecated? If so, what's a replacement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the solution is as weird as the bug itself.

Just added `InetGet("http://google.com")` at the script starting and everything works normally.

Perhaps Windows does not allow apps to open sockets after some time without a socket opened... Or it's really a bug (as I see topics around the web about this bug that are older even than me, I do think so).